# Ensure that there is only one running PHP process on Linux

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php script running each minute from cron. but sometimes it works longer than 1 minute.
My question is: what is the best way to ensure that only one process is running right now?

I use this code:

```
$output = shell_exec('ps aux | grep some_script.php | grep -v grep');   //get all processes containing "some_script.php" and exclude current grep process
$trimmed = rtrim($output, PHP_EOL); //trim newline symbol in the end
$processes = explode(PHP_EOL, $trimmed);    //get the array of lines (i.e. processes)
$procCnt = count($processes);   //get number of lines
if ($procCnt > 2) {
  echo "busy\n";
  exit();       //exit if number of processes more than 2 (see explaination below)
}
```

If there is one some_script process running from cron, shell_exec returns something like that:

```
apache     13593  0.0  0.0   9228  1068 ?        Ss   18:20   0:00 /bin/bash -c php -f /srv/www/robot/some_script.php 2>&1
apache     13602  0.0  0.0 290640 10544 ?        S    18:20   0:00 php -f /srv/www/robot/some_script.php
```

so if I have more than 2 lines in output, I call exit()

I want to ask: am I on a right way? Or is there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking that way creates a race condition where two processes can retrieve the list at the same time, then both decide to exit.  Depending on what you're trying to do, this may or may not be a problem.

A possible better alternative is to create a lock of some sort.  A simple one I've used is a directory that only exists while the process is running - [`mkdir`](https://www.php.net/mkdir) is atomic, it will either succeed (no other process is running) or fail (another process has already created it).  Just make sure to remove it when complete:

```
if (!mkdir("lock_dir")) {
   echo "busy\n";
   exit();
}
register_shutdown_function(function() {
   rmdir("lock_dir");
});
```

Or better, it looks like [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) was made for a similar purpose.  This is the example from the manual:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Just hold the lock for the script's runtime, similar to my first example.

Comment: I should add, _as far as I know_ PHP's mkdir is atomic.  If I'm wrong, then using flock with the shutdown function is probably better.

Comment: I didn't know about the register_shutdown_function. Thank you very much! It did the trick

Comment: The register_shutdown_function may not get called on certain types of error. To really make it work I would add "expiration" for the lock. check the filemtime of the folder and if it's more than let's say 15 minutes, delete it and proceed with the cron (you may also kill all php processes with your script).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is to create file while process start, and delete it at very end.
And check if file exist, then proceed and create it or die.

Another one is limit MaxClients for apache to one (if it is valid option in your case).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I thought about this method, but in case if there is a fatal error in a script (nobody is perfect), it will be terminated, and file will not be deleted

Comment: @Izkata 's answer has a solution for this - register_shutdown_function

Comment: @ZUb if file exist check its creation time (use stat function) - older than several minutes than delete and proceed as usual,

Answer (score 0):

Just for OOP style, I am using separated Helper class.

[flock — Portable advisory file locking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

[register_shutdown_function — Register a function for execution on shutdown](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

```
<?php

class ProcessHelper
{
    const PIDFILE = 'yourProcessName.pid';

    public static function isLocked()
    {
        $fp = fopen(self::PIDFILE, 'w');

        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB, $wouldBlock)) {
            if ($wouldBlock) {
                // if this file locked by other process
                var_dump('DO NOTHING');
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            var_dump('Do something and remove PID file');
            register_shutdown_function(function () {
                unlink(self::PIDFILE);
            });
            sleep(5); //for test, uncomment
        }
        return false;
    }
}


class FooService
{
    public function init()
    {
        if (!ProcessHelper::isLocked()) {
            var_dump('count 1000\n');
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
                echo $i;
            }
        }
    }
}

$foo = new FooService();
$foo->init();
```